# Qt - Making a Splitter Horizontal and Vertical at same time

Tags: qt, qsplitter

I have a `QGridLayout` with a `QSplitter` on it. In that `QSplitter` I have two elements with a splitter that lets me move the splitter from left to right. Fine, there it's fine. But then I want to add another splitter but that moves up to down. (I'll explain with an image.)

[image: split window with two boxes atop a single wide box]

So it's mostly having 2 splitters, one that moves left-to-right and other that moves up-to-down.

I hope you understand.

```
QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout(this);
QSplitter *splitter = new QSplitter();
text1 = new QPlainTextEdit();
text2 = new QPlainTextEdit();
splitter->addWidget(text1);
splitter->addWidget(text2);
text1->resize(800, this->height());
layout->addWidget(splitter, 1, 0);
browser = new QTextBrowser();
browser->resize(1, 1);
layout->addWidget(browser, 2, 0);
setLayout(layout);
```

Here i add only 1 splitter, since i don't know how to do the 2nd one.

Comment: Can you add the source code that builds your `QGridLayout` and adds the splitter?

Comment: @sarnold: There edited first post.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should be able to adapt this for your needs easily. The idea is to create a container for the first two elements, then connect the container with the 3rd element all via splitters.

```
#include <QtGui>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QWidget wnd;

    QTextEdit *editor1 = new QTextEdit;
    QTextEdit *editor2 = new QTextEdit;
    QTextEdit *editor3 = new QTextEdit;

    QSplitter *split1 = new QSplitter;
    QSplitter *split2 = new QSplitter;

    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;

    QWidget *container = new QWidget;
    QVBoxLayout *container_layout = new QVBoxLayout;

    split1->addWidget(editor1);
    split1->addWidget(editor2);

    container_layout->addWidget(split1);
    container->setLayout(container_layout);

    split2->setOrientation(Qt::Vertical);
    split2->addWidget(container);
    split2->addWidget(editor3);

    layout->addWidget(split2);

    wnd.setLayout(layout);

    wnd.show();

    return app.exec();


}
```

Comment: Super, this also resolves some bugs in Qt when you insert layouts inside QSplitter!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868495/qt-qsplitter-and-unresponsive-gui-cpu-100